# Position fixed div to stick inside the parent

Tags: html, css

My code goes like this,

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container { position: relative; }
.button { position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0;  }
```

This is a responsive page and width of the container is dynamically changing when re-sizing the window. I want to stick the `.button` inside the container at top right side even the page is scrolling. But my code shows the `.button` outside the `.container` at top right of the screen.

Please help me fix this.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: what if change .button position to relative?

Comment: I need to stick the .button when page scrolling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `position: absolute` for this.

```
.container { position: relative; }
.button { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
```

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynt2f/).

`position: fixed` is positioned against the window, not the parent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my scenario is to stick the .button when page scrolling also it should be inside the container. Is there are any other ways to do this?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean - do you want the .container to be fixed to the page, so the button will remain inside it when scrolling? Could you clarify it some more?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know `position:fixed;` is relative to main window, not to parennt.